# Checking string for different date patterns in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I'm parsing a list of strings that supposed to be in date format, but some are missing month and/or day. What's the best implementation to make sure that data is being parsed correctly?

Let's assume we have a list like this:

```py
dates = d = ['2015-01-01', '2015-02', '2015']
```

It can be done with this code, but I'm pretty sure it's not an efficient way to do this:

```py
from datetime import datetime
parsed = []
for i in d:
    try:
        parsed.append(datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d').date())
    except Exception:
        try:
            parsed.append(datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m').date())
        except:
            parsed.append(datetime.strptime(i, '%Y').date())
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: This is a bit vague. What sort of efficiency/performance boost are you expecting and why isn't the current code performant enough? Are these the only three formats you're expecting to parse? More details/clarifications would be great. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen, The goal is to extract the most of the data. I want to add another try statement to pass None for anything else. So wondering if there's a better method to capture most of the data, avoiding None as much as possible.

Comment: All right--would you be able to make an example that shows every format you expect and clearly shows which ones are failing? Otherwise, it looks like your existing implementation already does the job on the sample list.

Comment: Thanks! It's part of a web scrapping app and I'm not sure what would it face later down the road. The code is what crossed my mind and I thought there should be a better implementation rather than chaining try statements.

Comment: There's probably an infinite number of ways that a string could be formatted as a date and I think it'd be premature/impossible to try to begin imagining them all. If the code works as it stands, it might be better asked on Code Review, although it's probably too insubstantial for that. See [CR on topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting there. As for your request here, you could put the formats in a list and iterate over them with one `try/except` in the loop so you don't have to nest them.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! that should work.